# CMake: Linking to an imported library with dependencies fails

Tags: cmake

I have a subdirectory with a CMakeLists.txt which should compile a library using make and export the result as an imported library to the parent directory:

```
set(static_lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/mylib.a)

add_custom_command(
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT ${static_lib}
    COMMAND make
    COMMAND make install PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(compile_mylib DEPENDS ${static_lib})

add_library(mylib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET mylib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${static_lib})
add_dependencies(mylib compile_mylib)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the parent directory looks like this:

```
add_subdirectory(deps/mylib)
add_executable(mybin source.c)
target_link_libraries(mybin mylib)
```

On OSX this works just fine - but if I compile the same on Ubuntu it seems to ignore the subdirectory's CMakeLists and complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: cannot find -lmylib
```

I'm using Clang for compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add GLOBAL to your add_library call so that it is visible to the parent CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
find_library(MYLIB mylib.a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
```

then set your link libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(mybin ${MYLIB})
```

should be work.